# can't manually update a mysql database containing text fields with c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm struggling with the problem of updating a MySQL database using a Windows Forms app. The code looks like this:

```
global_data.MyDA.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE words SET word = @word WHERE id = @id", global_data.connection);
global_data.MyDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
    new MySqlParameter("@word", MySqlDbType.Text, 0x7FFF, ParameterDirection.Input, false,
    0, 0, "word", DataRowVersion.Proposed, (object)edtWord.Text));
global_data.MyDA.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
    new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.UInt32, 10, ParameterDirection.Input, false,
    0, 0, "id", DataRowVersion.Proposed, (object)current_id)); 
global_data.MyDA.Update(table);
```

However, it fails to update anything (in this case - replacing a string value with `edtWord.Text`).
Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Can paste error ? please add a try, cath and paste exception to we get more details.

Comment: Are you sure that in your table are present changes? (I.E. Calling table.GetChanges as a test returns something?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are trying to update the backend database with changes in the table object. That's fine for the Update method of a DataAdapter and when the table is binded to some UI control (a DataGridView for example) that changes its underlying datasource.

But if you have a simple unbound textbox and you want to update a record in the database the correct approach is to define a command and execute it

```
string cmdText = "UPDATE words SET word = @word WHERE id = @id";
using(MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, cn))
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", edtWord.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", current_id);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note I have simplified the Parameter syntax for the sake of readability, not to imply that your code is wrong

Comment: If you update the DataGridView (enable editing) then your underlying datatable (I assume you have binded it to the DataGridView) will receive the user made changes and you call the Update method (no need to specify parameters) but if you want to change just a textbox then you call my code above, no need to involve the viewonly datagridview and its datasource